# SwiftUI responsive design on all iphones

Tags: swiftui

I am building app to practise my swiftUI skills, I created design with figma and copying that to my xcode, I Think I did it well while my device was `Iphone 12 pro max`, but after switching to for example: `Iphone se` the whole design is ruined. How can I Fix design to look good on all iphones[image: iphone 12 pro max]

[image]

BTW I use `.offset`'s alot, is that the problem ?

```
        ZStack{
            Color("background").ignoresSafeArea()
            Image("Group 7").offset(x:-163)
            Image("Group 6").offset(x:150, y:-400)
            Image("Group 8").offset(x:150,y:50)
            VStack{
            Text("drink water").font(.custom("Lobster 1.4.otf", size: 60)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9, green: 0.93, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.center).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:4, x:0, y:4)
                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fitz Water"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 375, height: 251)
                    .clipped()
                .frame(width: 375, height: 251)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9791666865348816, green: 0.9628472328186035, blue: 0.9628472328186035, alpha: 0.25)), radius:25, x:0, y:20)
                Spacer()
                
        }
            VStack{
                Text("Today you have only drank: 0,5 Litres").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9, green: 0.93, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:4, x:0, y:4).offset(x:38)
                    .padding(10)
                Text("Which is not enough...").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9, green: 0.93, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:4, x:0, y:4).offset(x:-37)
                    .padding(10)
                Text("You need to drink ").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9, green: 0.93, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:4, x:0, y:4).offset(x:-57)
                    .padding(10)
                Text("1.5").font(.custom("Prompt Regular", size: 110)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.14, green: 0.73, blue: 1, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.center).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:1, x:0, y:2)
                Text("Litres more").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9, green: 0.93, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1))).tracking(-0.3).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:4, x:0, y:4).offset(x:-90)
                    .padding(10)
                Button(action: {
                    print("Edit button was tapped")
                }) {
                    Image("ASD")
                }.offset(x:180,y:50)
            }.position(x: 160, y: 550)
        }
```

Comment: "BTW I use .offset's alot, is that the problem ?" yep. Those are all hardcoded values - for example, `.position(x: 160, y: 550)`. This will place it at the point `(x: 160, y: 550)` no matter what device you're on.

Comment: So, let SwiftUI do the work for you. Think in terms of vertical stacks (`VStack`), horizontal stack (`HStack`), and spacers that push against views, forcing them apart (`Spacer()`). With just those 3 you can pretty much make any layout you want - you almost *never* need  `position` or `offset`.

Comment: @aheze yes, but how can I put those "blobs" `Group 6` `Group 7` etc images like in the first picture with `VStack` and `HStack`

Comment: Try to avoid fixed values like you did in the `.position(...)` and `.offset(...)`. as @aheze mentioned you should just use the `Stacks` and `Spacer` to position your elements.

Comment: What 'blobs' do you mean?

Comment: @yleyver: There is nothing to do in this stage, no one can help you. You cannot hard code the values, if you do it, you get the issues like this, you should think relative coding in general.

Comment: @swiftPunk I remember in front-end we could do any design in fixed resolution, Can I do the same in xCode like different Design on iphone SE and Iphone 12

Comment: @yleyver: You can not code for fixed size! it is impossible and inconvenient, if you want fixed size then you should use tons of `if` if iPhone 12, if iPhone 8, ... as I said, relative is the answer.

Comment: All right, Thank you guys for the solution <3